# Offering WCS 2.x responses as compressed GeoTIFF from Rasdaman

Tags: geotiff-tiff, ogc, wcs, compression, rasdaman

I have a Rasdaman WCS server. I use and support WCS 2.1.0 clients but would like to support WCS 2.x in general.

Rasdaman offers various georeferenced raster formats for the responses, such as `image/gtiff`. But these GeoTIFFs are provided uncompressed.

How can I enable clients to request and receive compressed GeoTIFF instead?

In an ideal solution they would be able to choose from a set of server-side predefined methods such as JPEG with an appropriate quality level and DEFLATE with an appropriate compression level. But any standardized means to request compressed GeoTIFF would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Rasdaman supports the GeoTIFF Coverage Encoding Profile https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=54813.

Have a look at the table 2 in the profile and try using `geotiff:compression` with some of the supported compression methods:

> one of: "None", "PackBits", "Huffman", "LZW", "JPEG", "Deflate”

Comment: Thanks! My server lists `<ows:Profile>http://www.opengis.net/spec/WCS_coverage-encoding_geotiff/1.0/</ows:Profile>` however requests for `image/gtiff` and `GEOTIFF:COMPRESSION=DEFLATE` fail with `Parameter 'geotiff:compression' is not valid in request.`

Comment: That is odd. If Rasdaman says that it supports the GeoTIFF extension then it should do it. This ticket does not help https://rasdaman.org/ticket/904#no1.